# Solve latin square with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to make a script that solves a latin square. I have a few questions.
1. How can I enter numbers I already know in my array
2. Do i use the right array?

I will need a small kick in the right direction to get this problem solved.
I only have the code to create an empty field, I dont know how to continue now.

```
var array = [];    
for (var x = 0; x<4; x++){    
    for (var y = 0; y<4; y++){    
        array.push([x,y,0]);
    }
}
```

EDIT 1:

I think I have found a way to enter the numbers, but it isn't working properly.

So i have the array[x,y,z] where z is the number in the square. So I could prompt every z in the two for loops, like:

```
var array = [];

for (var x = 0; x<4; x++){
for (var y = 0; y<4; y++){

    z = prompt("Enter numbers, 0 if empty ")    ;

    array.push([x,y,z]);

}


}
```

Thanks in advance!

EDIT1:
I got a start. Asking for the square is not neccesary, I can implement the square I want to know in my code.

What i have now:

```
var square = [[1,0,3],[2,0,1],[0,1,0]];

for(var a = 0; a<square.length; a++){
for(var b = 0; b<square.length; b++){
if(square[a][b] === 0) {
enter function here 

}    

}
}
```

Any kick in the right direction for the function to find the number that replaces the zero?
A hint might be enough!

EDIT2: Its important I use backtracking. Any clue?

Comment: "It isn't working properly": care to elaborate?

Comment: As for the rest of the problem, what would be the point if we just told you the solution?

Comment: I receive an error after I enter the first number.

Comment: OK. What is the error?

Comment: @Dave, that could help. Given the fact i am a beginner I will need some explanation of how the code works.

Comment: While seeing a full solution might help you in this specific case, it won't help you get into the programmer's mindset of breaking a large problem down into several smaller problems. Try just having a go at this and ask a question if you get stuck somewhere specific. As for the input thing, you could hard-code some numbers into the script to get going (without knowing more about your error I'm not sure why you're getting it; best guess is an anti-pester mechanism in the browser)

Comment: Thanks, @Dave. The problem is I have absolutely no clue how to create this script. This is because I never had lessons or something close to this. This assignment is enclosed in our final project in school, but our teacher that is "helping" us with this project is currently unavailable. We have no one to give us a push in the right direction. Like you said, ask if you get stuck somewhere specific. We are stuck already now, we dont even know how to start. Thats because we are new to javascript.

Comment: Kick, I got a start! Need some help though:)